# Jquery 'find' not working with data tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

I'm struggling to get the Jquery 'find' to work in the following code. I've stripped it down to the very basics. In short, what I'm trying to achieve is, I have two lists containing the same names. When the name is clicked on the top list, I want a more detailed box to toggle open below. Then when either is clicked again, the lower box will toggle closed again.

I assume something is wrong in the Jquery with the 'find'. The other part, which collects the ID works fine when the ID is sent to an alert.

I've looked through other answers and that find section is from another answer but it doesn't work in this example, so presumably I'm doing something wrong on some other level.

Bear in mind that just finding the div or paragraph element won't work for my full code. I've just put them in those tags for this example. I basically need to find (in this example), the para inside the correct div (obviously there's only one div here but loads in my full code).

```
<html>

<body>

<?php

    for ($x=0; $x<10; $x++) {
        echo "<p class = 'player_name' data-playerid = $x>Player $x</p>";
    }

    echo "<div class = 'individual_player_reports'>";
        for ($x=0; $x<10; $x++) {
            echo "<p class = 'player_name' data-playerid = $x>Player $x</p>";
        }
    echo "</div>";

?>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('.player_name').on('click',
            function() {
                var id = $(this).data().playerid;
                $('.individual_player_reports').find("[playerid='" + id + "']").toggle();
        });

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

`playerid !== data-playerid`

Data attributes are just like any other attributes. Use the full name of the attribute when using the attribute equals selector.

```
$('.player_name').on('click',function() {
  var id = $(this).data().playerid;
  $('.individual_player_reports').find("[data-playerid='" + id + "']").toggle();
});
```

```js
$('.player_name').on('click',function() {
  var id = $(this).data().playerid;
  $('.individual_player_reports').find("[data-playerid='" + id + "']").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="player_name" data-playerid='1'>1</p>
<p class="player_name" data-playerid='2'>2</p>
<p class="player_name" data-playerid='3'>3</p>
<div class="individual_player_reports">
  <p data-playerid='1' style="display: none;">1</p>
  <p data-playerid='2' style="display: none;">2</p>
  <p data-playerid='3' style="display: none;">3</p>
</div>
```

---

As @T.J. Crowder suggests, you don't need to use `.data()` in this case, it would be more efficient to skip `.data` and just get the attribute value directly to avoid initializing the data cache unless you are using `.data()`'s features elsewhere too.

```
var id = $(this).attr('data-playerid');
```

Comment: Ah, yes, I see it. With you.

Comment: (I'd also suggest that unless actually using `data`'s features, just use `attr("data-playerid")` to get the value. No need to initialize the data cache and populate it if it's not going to be used.)

Comment: Thank you, this has solved my issue. Not sure how I managed to miss the 'data' in 'data-playerid', but so many syntax issues, I'm surprised I even got this close. And I didn't know about the data cache so thanks for that info too.